# Change database connection per request in Play 2.4.2

Tags: database, postgresql, dynamic, playframework, database-connection

I am using Play 2.4.2 and i am trying to connect to different PostgreSQL databases on runtime.

There is one (legacy) PostgreSQL installation running on the same host, but it has (right now ~39) databases.

For each request based on the route i want to connect to a different database dynamically without specifying each datasource in application.conf.

I know this is neither a good nor an efficient solution, i'm just interested whether this is possible at all.

Comment: Can't you configure all those DBs as persistance units in your `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml` and then access them via JPA.em("persistanceUnitName")?

Comment: Well i didn't think of that yet, i'll look into it.